# Object is not a function (MVC Javascript)

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

When I run my app there is an error `

> "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/js/controller.js (2)

I have a class model.js :

```
var posAttuale = {
    myLat : "myLat",
    myLng : "myLng",
    myComune : "myComune"
};
```

and a class controller.js :

```
    var infoPos = new posAttuale; //Error is here
   //....rest of program....
```

How can I fix the error?

`

Comment: Well like the error says its not a function, its an object, you cannot call `new` on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call it as a constructor, and define it as a constuct function:

```
var posAttuale = function() {
    this.myLat = "myLat";
    this.myLng = "myLng";
    this.myComune = "myComune";
};

var infoPos = new posAttuale();
```

Comment: I didn't notice that you first define `posAttuale` as `object`, so I didn't alter it. Now I just changed all your code.